# Why it isn't this div centered? I can't understand

Tags: html, css, alignment

```html
<div style="border-radius:50px 10px;width:60%;border: 1px solid #123467;background:linear-gradient(to top, #88D3CE 0%, #6E45e2 100%);display:inline-block;float:right">
  <div style="align:center;border-radius:10px 50px;margin-top:5%;text-align:center;width:60%;border: 1px solid #ffffff;background:linear-gradient(-225deg,#A445B2 0%, #D41872 52%, #FF0066 100%)">
    <br/>
  <h3 style="color:black">Running from</h3>
 </div>
 <br/>
</div>
```

The blue, pink, violet div isn't center despite I insert the align tag also in style (CSS). Why?

Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `float: right` is the main problem which forces the outer DIV to the right side. Remove that. To horizontally center it, you can make it a block element and add `auto` for margin-right and left.

So, you should apply `display:block; margin: 0 auto;` to both DIVs and remove the `float` (actually, to keep your 5% margin-top, the `margin` setting for the inner DIV has to be `margin: 5% auto 0;`)

```html
<div style="border-radius:50px 10px;width:60%;border: 1px solid #123467;background:linear-gradient(to top, #88D3CE 0%, #6E45e2 100%);display:block;margin: 0 auto;">
  <div style="align:center;border-radius:10px 50px;text-align:center;width:60%;border: 1px solid #ffffff;display:block;margin: 5% auto 0;background:linear-gradient(-225deg,#A445B2 0%, #D41872 52%, #FF0066 100%)">
    <br/>
    <h3 style="color:black">Running from</h3>
  </div>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could add `margin: 5% auto;` to your inner DIV:

```
<style>
    #firstDiv
    {
        border-radius:50px 10px;
        width:60%;
        border: 1px solid #123467;
        background:linear-gradient(to top, #88D3CE 0%, #6E45e2 100%);
        display:inline-block;
        float:right;
    }

    #secondDiv {
        border-radius:10px 50px;
        margin: 5% auto;
        width:60%;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff;
        background:linear-gradient(-225deg,#A445B2 0%, #D41872 52%, #FF0066 100%);
        text-align: center;
    }

    #secondDiv h3 {
        color: black;
    }
</style>

<div id="firstDiv" style="">
    <div id="secondDiv" style="">
        <h3>Running from</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

However I suggest separating styles and html.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such CSS property "align". Instead, use the margin property and set its values to 0 (for top and bottom), as well as auto (for left and right). This will center the element.

```css
.outer {
  border-radius: 50px 10px;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid #123467;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #88D3CE 0%, #6E45e2 100%);
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px 50px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  background: linear-gradient(-225deg,#A445B2 0%, #D41872 52%, #FF0066 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <br/>
  <h3 style="color:black">Running from</h3>
 </div>
 <br/>
</div>
```